# Swift closures and Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have a facade based design for the project due to customer requirements. I would like to know which method having the least memory consumptions and which is the better method.

```
class ModFirst: NSObject {
    func getCells(tableView: UITableView, rtn: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) {
        print("ModFirst- getCells")
        TableCellFirst().cells(tableView: tableView, rtn: { (cells) in
           rtn(cells)
        })
    }
}


class ModThird: NSObject {
   lazy var tableCellThird: TableCellThird? = TableCellThird()
   func getCellsNew(rtn: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) {
       print("ModThird - getCellsNew")
       self.tableCellThird?.cellsNew(rtn: { (cells) in
          rtn(cells)
       })
   }

   deinit {
      print("deinit - ModThird")
      self. tableCellThird = nil
   }

}
```

The above are the two different ways of implementations. The first method instantly allocates TableCellFirst object and calls getCells method. This implementation does not have any memory leaks. But the second implementation uses lazy variables and deinit but it still having the memory leak while Profiling with Instruments.

So which is the best method to follow and which will be safer in the case of leaks?

Comment: see this : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

Answer (score 1):

It can be not obvious, but you have a strong reference cycle in the second case(my guess it's in the `rtn` closure definition). You can define a capture list in your closure to avoid that.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

> Each item in a capture list is a pairing of the weak or unowned keyword with a reference to a class instance (such as self) or a variable initialized with some value (such as delegate = self.delegate!). These pairings are written within a pair of square braces, separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of **tableCellThird** property holds a strong reference to its closure(**rtn:**).

If you capture reference through **self** keyword so it will be hold strong reference .

So you need to use your property without **self** keyword as below .

```
tableCellThird?.cellsNew(rtn: { (cells) in
          rtn(cells)
       })
```